# How React Redux component can subscribe on state change

Tags: javascript, redux

I have some "ChangeMainItem" Action (in my case it is dispatched by external system or possibly one of components). This action (e.g. `{type:Change_Main_Item, itemId:5}`) updates only one property of state in reducer (e.g. `mainItemId`).

My Component A and B needs to react on this state change: show loading indicator, fetch additional data and show results. Sequential actions can be done via some async action library - but where should I place dispatching async action? Obviously, i can't dispatch async action in reducer of Component A and B, neither i want to change original Action to async so it can make any necessary requests for my components.

What is the right way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using sagas to listen to your defined actions and manage your async calls/actions from there. Redux-saga is awesome.

```
import { put, takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import {Change_Main_Item, ANOTHER_ACTION, THIRD_ACTION} from '../actions'


function* doSomething() {
      yield put({type: "ANOTHER_ACTION", payload: data});
}

function* doAnotherThing() {
      yield put({type: "THIRD_ACTION", payload: data});
}

function* mySaga() {
  yield takeEvery("Change_Main_Item", [doSomething, doAnotherThing]);
}
```

Please see https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga

Comment: So using Redux-saga I can add async request in doSomething? Something like this?
`function* doSomething() {const data = yield call(Api.fetchData, action.payload.mainItemId); 
yield put({type: "DATA_FETCH_SUCCEEDED", data: data}); }`

And then create sagaComponentA: `yield takeEvery("Change_Main_Item", doSomethingA)` (and the same for Component B)

Comment: Yes.. Sagas are especially useful to manage all the side effects (async ,etc)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have multiple approaches to such a question.

You can use a redux-thunk so you can dispatch multiple actions and have your state react to all such dispatches. Thunk middleware is useful when you need to perform async actions.

example:

```
function changeMainItem(id) {
  return (dispatch, getState) {
    dispatch(requestChangeMainItem); //This tells the state that it's loading some ajax; you presumably want to add some boolean, indicating a loading icon.
    return makeSomeRequest(id)
      .then(data => {
        dispatch(changeMainItem(data.id)) //presumably, this is where you update your item
        // perhaps dispatch another function to do more stuff.
      })
  }
}
```

You then will need to figure out which components need to be subscribed/connected to certain properties in your state.

Read about [async action](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html), [redux-thunks](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk), and [this article on how to connect your components to your state](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html)

Comment: I thought about this, but i don't like idea that action knows too much. So if i need to make like 10 requests to show 2-3 components than i need to create this very big actionCreator (via redux-thunk or other). I still hope that there is a way to subscribe on property update, so each component knows what data to request?